# R data.table ':=' works in direct call, but same function in a package fails

Tags: r, data.table, colon-equals

Using R's data.table package,

This works:

```
instruction = "a = data.table(name=1:3, value=1:3, blah=1:3); a[,c('value', 'blah'):=NULL]"
eval(parse(text=instruction))
#   name
#1:    1
#2:    2
#3:    3
```

This works:

```
myFunc = function(instruction) {
eval(parse(text=instruction))
}
myFunc(instruction)
#   name
#1:    1
#2:    2
#3:    3
```

Now, put this function into a package, load it, and try to call it. This doesn't work:

```
myFuncInPackage(instruction)
#Error in `:=`(c("value", "blah"), NULL) : 
#  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").
```

Why?

---

EDIT: @Roland points out that adding data.table in the package `Depends` field makes it work. However, I don't think this is a great solution because the package doesn't really depend on, require, or use data.table. I just want to be able to use data.table with the package.

In addition, everything else with data.table works fine in the function, just not the `:=` operator.

So I guess a followup question could be: should I add data.table to the Depends of every package I write, so that data.tables work as expected within functions of that package? This doesn't seem right... what is the correct way to approach this?

Comment: Have you followed the advice in [FAQ 6.9](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.pdf)? Also, use of `eval(parse())` is discouraged from.

Comment: @Roland Add data.table to Depends solves it... but leads to an issue: my package doesn't actually depend on data.table; in fact, it's totally unrelated. As in this example, it just has one function, `myFunc` -- no data.table anything. But it can't be used with data.table without adding it to Depends...

Comment: @Roland, I know, `eval(parse())` is discouraged, and this is a pointless example, but the question still stands...in some cases I can't get around it.

Comment: Your package has `eval(parse(text=instruction))` where `instruction` can be anything! At the time of evaluation any function required by `instruction` must be available; this should be specified in the usage instructions for your package. You're seeing this when `instruction` requires a function in `data.table`; load 'data.table' before executing `myFuncInPackage(instruction)` and see if it works.

Comment: The `:=` operator that you use in _your_ function is defined within `data.table` package, so yes, your package _does_ depend on `data.table`

Comment: @ Sergii Zaskaleta No... I didn't use `:=` in my function. That was passed by the user, in the "instruction" variable. it has _nothing_ to do with the package...

Comment: @sheffien can you check if you did update your `NAMESPACE` file to `import(data.table)` and `DESCRIPTION` to `Imports: data.table`? I got the same problem recently just because missing entry in `NAMESPACE` file.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376593/do-we-need-the-colon-equals-tag

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've finally figured out the answer to this question (after several years). All comments and answers suggested adding `data.table` to `Depends` or `Imports`, but this is incorrect; the package does not depend on `data.table` and, that could be any package hypothetically, not just data.table, meaning taken to logical conclusion, the suggestion would require adding all possible packages to `Depends` -- since that dependency is provided by the user providing the `instruction`, not by the function provided by the package.

Instead, basically, it's because call to `eval` is done within the namespace of the package, and this does not include the functions provided by other packages. I ultimately solved this by specifying the global environment in the `eval` call:

```
myFunc = function(instruction) {
eval(parse(text=instruction), envir=globalenv())
}
```

**Why this works**

This causes the `eval` function to be done in the environment that will include the requisite packages in the search path.

In the `data.table` case it's particularly hard to debug because of the complexity of the function overloading. In this case, the culprit is not actually the `:=` function, but the `[` function. The `:=` error is a red herring. At the time of writing, the `:=` function in `data.table` is defined like this:

https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/348c0c7fdb4987aa6da99fc989431d8837877ce4/R/data.table.R#L2561

`` ":=" <- function(...) stop('Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").') ``

That's it. What that means: any call to `:=` as a function is stopped with an error message, because this is not how the authors intend `:=` to be used. Instead, `:=` is really just keyword that's interpreted by the `[` function in `data.table`.

But what happens here: if the `[` function isn't correctly mapped to the version specified by `data.table`, and instead is mapped to the base `[`, then we have a problem -- since it can't handle `:=` and so it's getting treated as a function and triggering the error message. So the culprit function is `[.data.table` -- the overloaded bracket operator.

What's happening is in my new package (that holds `myFuncInPackage`), when it goes to evaluate the code, it resolves the `[` function to the base `[` function instead of to `data.table`'s `[` function. It tries to evaluate `:=` as a function, which is not being consumed by the `[` since it's not the correct `[`, so `:=` is getting passed as a function instead of as a value to `data.table`'s, because `data.table` is not in the namespace (or is lower in the `search()` hierarchy. In this setting, `:=` is not understood and so it's being evaluated as a function, thus triggering the error message in the `data.table` code above.

When you specify the eval to happen in the global environment, it correctly resolves the `[` function to `[.data.table`, and the `:=` is interpreted correctly.

Incidentally, you can also use this if you're passing not a character string but a code block (better) to `eval()` inside a package:

`eval(substitute(instruction), envir=globalenv())`

Here, `substitute` prevents the `instruction` from being parsed (incorrectly) within the package namespace at the argument-eval stage, so that it makes it intact back to the globalenv where it can be correctly evaluated with the required functions in place.

Answer (score 8):

I had same problem and I solved it adding `data.table` to `Imports` and `Depends:`. My `data.table` version is `1.9.6`

Comment: Can you give an example? - - I have script which sources a function which uses `data.table`. I get the error here. I include `library(data.table)` in the script and/or in the function itself. - - Can you also give an example how you apply `Imports` and `Depends:` here to solve the problem. My data.table is 1.10.4.

Comment: It worked for me in R package context - not raw script. But answering to your question - you can apply it in `DESCRIPTION` file:
`Imports: data.table (>= 1.9.6) Depends:  data.table (>= 1.9.6) `, e.g.: https://pastebin.com/uy10Devh

Comment: Can you prevent packages to be loaded by such specifications? Etc `imports data.table` but prevent `reshape2` to be loaded as an own package.

Comment: You can load only specific functions from package by using `@import`, e.g.: `@importFrom jsonlite toJSON unbox`. Read more here: http://kbroman.org/pkg_primer/pages/depends.html

Comment: @Taz you can do this, but it doesn't solve the underlying problem; it only solves it for this package, not for other potential issues. See my new answer for a universal solution.

Comment: In my case, it was enough to just mention `Imports: data.table` in the `DESCRIPTION` file. Even more, mentioning again in `Depends:` section would trigger a note from `devtools::check()` - `Package listed in more than one of Depends, Imports, Suggests, Enhances: data.table A package should be listed in only one of these fields.`

Comment: I added `data.table` in depends and it works finally, removed from imports. This is extremely annoying, wasted 3 hours on this. Yikes.