# How can I drop observations within a group following the occurrence of NA?

Tags: r

I am trying to clean my data. One of the criteria is that I need an uninterrupted sequence of a variable "assets", but I have some NAs. However, I cannot simply delete the NA observations, but need to delete all subsequent observations following the NA event.

Here an example:

```
productreference<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5)
Year<-c(2000,2001,2002,2003,1999,2000,2001,2005,2006,2007,2008,1998,1999,2000,2000,2001,2002,2003)
assets<-c(2,3,NA,2,34,NA,45,1,23,34,56,56,67,23,23,NA,14,NA)
mydf<-data.frame(productreference,Year,assets)
mydf

#    productreference Year assets
# 1                 1 2000      2
# 2                 1 2001      3
# 3                 1 2002     NA
# 4                 1 2003      2
# 5                 2 1999     34
# 6                 2 2000     NA
# 7                 2 2001     45
# 8                 3 2005      1
# 9                 3 2006     23
# 10                3 2007     34
# 11                3 2008     56
# 12                4 1998     56
# 13                4 1999     67
# 14                4 2000     23
# 15                5 2000     23
# 16                5 2001     NA
# 17                5 2002     14
# 18                5 2003     NA
```

I have already seen that there is a way to carry out functions by group using plyr and I have also been able to create a column with 0-1, where 0 indicates that assets has a valid entry and 1 highlights missing values of NA.

```
mydf$missing<-ifelse(mydf$assets>=0,0,1)
mydf[c("missing")][is.na(mydf[c("missing")])] <- 1
```

I have a very large data set so cannot manually delete the rows and would greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: Do you want this done using `productreference` as a grouping variable?

Comment: halfway guessing here `mydf[!is.na(ave(assets, productreference, FUN = cumsum)), ]`

Comment: Since we have `dplyr` and `data.table` answers, I'll annotate rawr's comment to say that's how you'd do it in base.

Comment: Yes, I did mean by productreference, than you. I just tried the "base-way" of doing this but I get an error called "Error in interaction(...) : object 'productreference' not found". Any ideas what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `base R` option

```
mydf[unsplit(lapply(split(mydf, mydf$productreference),
     function(x) cumsum(is.na(x$assets))==0), mydf$productreference),]    
#   productreference Year assets
#1                 1 2000      2
#2                 1 2001      3
#5                 2 1999     34
#8                 3 2005      1
#9                 3 2006     23
#10                3 2007     34
#11                3 2008     56
#12                4 1998     56
#13                4 1999     67
#14                4 2000     23
#15                5 2000     23
```

---

Or an option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydf)[, if(any(is.na(assets))) .SD[seq(which(is.na(assets))[1]-1)] 
                    else .SD, by = productreference]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, both these approaches worked perfectly. Are there any pros or cons of using the base R approach over plyr or data.table? With over 230,000 observations I am worried about running time...

Comment: 230,000 isn't *so* big. `dplyr` will probably be faster than `base`, and `data.table` will be the fastest. The difference will probably be a few seconds--maybe less between the `dplyr` and `data.table` versions--which if you're running it once won't much matter. But the real answer is to try it and see!

Answer (score 5):

I believe this is what you want:

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(mydf, productreference) %>%
    filter(cumsum(is.na(assets)) == 0)
# Source: local data frame [11 x 3]
# Groups: productreference [5]
# 
#    productreference  Year assets
#               (dbl) (dbl)  (dbl)
# 1                 1  2000      2
# 2                 1  2001      3
# 3                 2  1999     34
# 4                 3  2005      1
# 5                 3  2006     23
# 6                 3  2007     34
# 7                 3  2008     56
# 8                 4  1998     56
# 9                 4  1999     67
# 10                4  2000     23
# 11                5  2000     23
```

Comment: Thank you, that is looking promising! Unfortunately, I also get an error here: "Error: could not find function "%>%"." Do I need to install any further packages?

Comment: What version of `dplyr` do you have? `%.%` was deprecated and replaced with `%>%` in version 0.2 (May 2014)... the current version is something like 0.4.3...

Comment: I have version 1.8.4; I just ran the command "update.packages()", but a new version of plyr was not offered. Am I getting something wrong or do I have the most current version?

Comment: You say `plyr`, I say `dplyr`.The `d` matters. `dplyr` is more-or-less a replacement for `plyr`. It's focused only on data frames (unlike `plyr` which works for lists and arrays too) but is *much* more efficient (and more user-friendly too).

Answer (score 3):

Here is the same approach using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(mydf)

dt[,nas:= cumsum(is.na(assets)),by="productreference"][nas==0]

#    productreference Year assets nas
# 1:                1 2000      2   0
# 2:                1 2001      3   0
# 3:                2 1999     34   0
# 4:                3 2005      1   0
# 5:                3 2006     23   0
# 6:                3 2007     34   0
# 7:                3 2008     56   0
# 8:                4 1998     56   0
# 9:                4 1999     67   0
#10:                4 2000     23   0
#11:                5 2000     23   0
```

Comment: It will hep to set keys for a big data set.

Comment: That would be great, as I will need to do further analysis by "productreference"! Unfortunately, I get the error: "Error in `[.data.frame`(small, , `:=`(nas, cumsum(is.na(estimatedassets))),  : 
  unused argument (by = "productreference")". Could this be because I have the wrong type for productreference? I imported it as a numeric...

Comment: You need to do this: `dt <- as.data.table(mydf)`. You also need to load/install the `data.table` package. You're getting this error because you're trying to use `data.table` operations on a `data.frame` so you need to convert it using the above code.

Comment: I have converted to a data.table as you suggested and run the third line again. Am still getting an error: "Error in `:=`(nas, cumsum(is.na(estimatedassets))) : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways." I just read the help for ":=", but am still none the wiser.

Comment: A quick google of your error gives this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27980835/r-data-table-works-in-direct-call-but-same-function-in-a-package-fails. Are you trying to use this call in a package?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using base R and a for loop. This code is a bit longer than some of the code in the other answers. In the loop we subset `mydf` by `productreference` and for every subset we look for the first occurrence of `assets==NA`, and exclude that row and all following rows.

```
mydf2 <- NULL
for (i in 1:max(mydf$productreference)){
  s1 <- mydf[mydf$productreference==i,]
  s2 <- s1[1:ifelse(all(!is.na(s1$assets)), NROW(s1), min(which(is.na(s1$assets)==T))-1),]
  mydf2 <- rbind(mydf2, s2)
  mydf2 <- mydf2[!is.na(mydf2$assets),]
}
mydf2
```

Comment: Thank you, this also worked nicely. It did create about 7 additional empty observations in the first few rows, but simply shifted the data frame. So no problem to simply delete the rows afterwards.

Comment: You're right, and that's because I forgot to exclude rows with assets==NA when they were first in a subset based on productreference. I changed it in the code above. Thanks.